What is the best way to use a recursive function in a Kotlin Coroutine so that it can be cancelled and restarted?
I am trying to run a recursive function on a background thread and be able to cancel it and restart it when the user clicks a button. I have read through some coroutine basics but still not getting the hang of it. Can anyone suggest the best solution?
Also, I'm trying to choose between two versions of the recursive function. One returns its value up through the stack, while the other just updates a class property without returning. Both seem to work properly with the second one finishing slightly faster.
Are there any inherent issues with running a recursive function without returns?
Here is my code. It compiles and runs properly in the android emulator (of course I need to click "Wait" on the ANR popup).
The sample data finishes in about 95 or 91 seconds. In reality the list could contain any number of Items with each having a list of any number of integers.
The intention is for the user to submit a set of data for the purpose of calculating probabilies. The function (at this point) counts the total possible combinations. The user should not need to wait for a calculation to complete before clicking the button to submit a new set of data which should cancel the currently running job (if one exists) and start over again with the new data set.
data class Item(var numbers: List<Int>)

class CalcEngine(

) {
    val data: List<Item> = listOf(
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
        Item( listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ),
    )

    fun calculate() {
        val time1 = measureTimeMillis {
            Log.d(TAG, "starting countWithReturn()...")
            Log.d(TAG, "count: ${countWithReturn()}")
            Log.d(TAG, "done.")
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Completed in ${time1 / 1000L }s.")
        // sample data finishes in 95s.
        Log.d(TAG, "")

        testCount = 0UL
        val time2 = measureTimeMillis {
            Log.d(TAG, "starting countNoReturn()...")
            countNoReturn()
            Log.d(TAG, "count: $testCount")
            Log.d(TAG, "done.")
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Completed in ${time2 / 1000L }s.")
        // sample data finishes in 91s.
        Log.d(TAG, "===================================")
        Log.d(TAG, "")
    }

    fun countWithReturn(index: Int = 0): ULong {
        if(index == data.size - 1 ) {
            var count = 0UL
            for(i in 0..<data[index].numbers.size) { count++ }
            return count
        } else {
            var count = 0UL
            for (i in 0..<data[index].numbers.size) {
                count = count + countWithReturn(index + 1)
            }
            return count
        }
    }

    var testCount: ULong = 0UL
    fun countNoReturn(index: Int = 0) {
        if(index == data.size - 1 ) {
            for(i in 0..<data[index].numbers.size) { testCount++  }
        } else {
            for (i in 0..<data[index].numbers.size) { countNoReturn(index + 1) }
        }
    }
}


Please [edit] the question and clarify what the intended behavior is for multiple calls to calculate, especially when called from multiple threads.

You should use coroutines to control the execution of the calculation. When you make calculate (and countWithReturn and countNoReturn) a suspend function their execution can be cancelled. Since coroutines in Kotlin are cooperative, the part of the code that want's to honor a cancellation request must actively check if the current coroutine is still active by calling
coroutineContext.ensureActive()

This provides a breaking point where your function can be aborted and should be interspersed in your code wherever you want to allow the calculation to be stopped. In your example code a fitting place would be right at the start of countWithReturn and countNoReturn.
When you then call calculate from a coroutine you can cancel that at any time and start it anew. It could look like this:
class SomeContainer(val scope: CoroutineScope) {
    var job: Job? = null

    fun runCalculation() {
        job?.cancel()
        job = scope.launch {
            CalcEngine().calculate()
        }
    }
}

Whenever runCalculation is called the already running coroutine from the previous call (when it exists) is cancelled and a new coroutine is launched. This container class can be anything, f.e. your view model.
Just make sure to always create a new CalcEngine instance when you start a new calculation because you have a mutable instance variable there (testCount) which isn't thread-safe.

Please do not edit other people's posts to ask for clarification - that's what comments are for. What I gathered from your attempted edit is that you want to ask how you can create a CoroutineScope to pass to SomeContainer. As already mentioned you could use your view model as the container - and that has the viewModelScope already defined and ready to use. If you want to create SomeContainer in Compose (which you shouldn't, everything will be lost on device rotation), you could use rememberCoroutineScope() to obtain a scope.

I was able to run it using viewModelScope, but I still got the ANR popup and clicked the "Wait" option. Am I still missing something?

Also, the time to complete the counting function increased about 10 times (96s vs 1105s). Is this normal for using a background thread?

I was not able to see if the job can cancel properly, due to the frozen interface after the ANR.

Did you choose the correct dispatcher to run your calculations? When the calculation is CPU heavy you should use Dispatchers.Default.

After adding (Dispatchers.Default) to the launch function, the ANR stopped and I could cancel the job properly, however it still took 10 times the original amount of time to complete. (about 1010s). Is there a better way?

Today I noticed that while the job cancels if it is not null, it continues to be in "cancelling" status for some time while the new job is starting. So if several jobs are started and cancelled before completion, the new job runs slower as the cpu keeps cancelling the previous jobs. (my test showed 125s instead of the usual 87s.) Is it possible somehow to cancel a running job and immediately reclaim the cpu/ram for processing the new job?

I'm calling this one solved, since I think it was the creating a new CalcEngine object each time that fixed the errors/crashes I was experiencing. I'm still concerned though that the background thread takes about 5 times longer to complete (10x including the check for cancelling).
